# Convert multiple line shell script to one line command

Tags: c++, linux, shell, ssh

I use C++ app to compute results, then I use echo to print results in a file called a in Fedora linux.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd myapp
out=`time ./cppcode`
cd ..
echo $out >> a
```

I'm using ssh and average running time of myapp is 2 hour, so often ssh connection disappears and terminal stops responding. I can still ssh via another terminal and use `top` to see that my app is running, but after 2 hours no results are saved into a file.

I believe that if I execute one-line command, the results will be printed. Could you please tell me how to rewrite this script as one line?

Comment: You might want to use `screen`. Start the script via screen, detach from your screen session, go have some lunch and reattach to your session to view the progress.

Comment: Consider running `nohup time myapp/cppcode`; this will run the command, and time it, with the output (standard output and standard error) going to `./nohup.out`.  This will ignore the SIGHUP signal that is generated when the `ssh` session times out (hence `nohup`).  It is not clear why you do the `echo`; why not simply redirect the output from the command to file: `./myapp/cppcode >a` or variations on the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **don't** believe that changing the script to a single line will help you.  You can try that out yourself:

```
cd myapp; out=`time ./cppcode`; cd ..; echo $out >> a
```

or simpler:

```
(cd myapp; time ./cppcode) >> a
```

Please notice that redirecting only stdout will never capture the output of the `time` command.  If you want to redirect that, you can add sth like `2>> a.time_results` or simply add `2>&1` to redirect it into `a` as well.

I rather think that your connection is shutdown because its idle time is too high (no transmitted data for ten minutes or so).

A typical approach to solve such issues is to implement a decently fluent output, e. g. by printing a progress (maybe a progress bar or simple dots now and then).

Another approach would be to use terminal multiplexers like `screen` to be able to re-connect to a running session later, even if your ssh connection broke down in the meantime.  Simply start `ssh`, then within that shell start `screen`, then within that screen start your real stuff.  If your connection breaks, simply start `ssh` and then `screen -x` to reconnect to the running screen session.

Comment: the solution I'm trying now is indeed `screen`. Do you know the difference between `screen -x` and `screen -r` ?

Comment: With `-x` you can attach to undetached screen sessions as well (so it will work also if you still have a connection from elsewhere to the same session).  `-r` will only attach to detached sessions.  If the session is detached, both do the same.

Answer (score 0):

To try and perform the same thing with a single command:

```
#!/bin/bash
time myapp/cppcode 2>> a
```

should do it

(Assuming `cppcode` doesn't rely on the CWD being the `myapp` folder)

Though basically you're finding that subsequent commands don't get executed after your ssh connection fails

so

```
#!/bin/bash

cd myapp
time ./cppcode 2>> ../a
cd ..
```

should at least ensure the output always gets written (since the only command to get lost would be the `cd ..` )

Answer (score -1):

```
cd myapp
time ./cppcode >> ../a
```

or if your app doesn't depend on the current directory:

```
time myapp/cppcode >> a
```